# I am looking filter excel data based on user input in power apps

Tags: powerapps

I am new to Powerapps and currently looking to filter values that are greater than user input values from sharepoint,

Eg: There are two columns in Sharepoint excel "Column A" and "Column B", If a user inputs a value "5" program should find the value greater than 5 in "Column A" and list the values from Column B as a dropdown.

Thanks for your assistance in advance!

I tried some scripts but dint work the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Filter(ExcelSource, ColumnA>Value(TextInput.Text))

Then define "field" of dropdown as "ColumnB".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried writing the code for the dropdown but not able to select Field.